# How to show contents of gulp stream in console

Tags: gulp

I am trying to debug a gulp pipeline, and want to inspect the contents of the data going through the pipe.  How can I have the data echoed to the console, mid-pipeline?

EG if I have something like this:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function() {
    return gulp.src(input_files)
    .pipe(first_process())
    .pipe(second_process())
    .pipe(display_data_in_console())
    .pipe(final_process())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination_path));
});
```

What can I use for the `display_data_in_console()` part?